# Nginx can't get real ip address because realip_remote_addr and remote_addr have same value

Tags: nginx, logging

**$realip_remote_addr** and **$remote_addr** have equal values for all combinations of lines defined
inside html block:

- set_real_ip_from  192.168.2.1;
- real_ip_header    X-Real-IP; or real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
- with or without: real_ip_recursive on;

with logging format:
'realip="$realip_remote_addr" '
'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request"

I always get the same values for **$realip_remote_addr** and **$remote_addr**, e.g.

"realip="192.168.2.1" 192.168.2.1 - - [19/Jun/2020:09:32:23 +0200] "GET"...

I expect and want something like: "realip="132.156.21.41" 192.168.2.1 - - [19/Jun/2020:09:32:23 +0200] "GET"...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values of `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For`. Because that is where the *real* value will be copied from.

Comment: @RichardSmith do you know how to see that from nginx?

Comment: You could add `$http_x_real_ip` and `$http_x_forwarded_for` to the access log. Notice that `-` are replaced by `_`.

Comment: For "xh="$http_x_forwarded_for" xr="$http_x_real_ip" " I get: "xh="-" xr="-" realip="192.168.2.1" 192.168.2.1 "

Comment: So the problem is with the downstream server. Nginx cannot know the real IP unless the previous server in the chain informs it somehow.

Comment: I understand, thanks Richard. I must say that I don't use any server in front of nginx, only router with open port forwarding to server machine. Could router be the problem?

Comment: The router at `192.168.2.1` seems to be behaving as a reverse proxy. Maybe you can configure it differently or get it to add a header with the real IP address.

Comment: Sounds like the router is not doing the port forwarding correctly. You should look into its configuration.

Comment: I use cloudflare and I only set proxy status to 'dns lookup'. When changed to 'proxy' headers that I cloudflare adds could be used for real_user_ip address. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use cloudflare and I only set proxy status to 'dns lookup'. When changed to 'proxy' headers that I cloudflare adds could be used for real_user_ip address.